# Xcode 12 fails to add watchOS 4.2 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, watchkit, watchos-4

I want to build an app with WatchKit extension with watchOS 4.2 deployment target (for Apple Watch Gen0 support) in Xcode 12.4. I have iOS 14.4 and watchOS 4.2 simulators downloaded. But when i try to add paired watch to any iOS simulator and select "Apple Watch - 42mm" as device, the components windows instantly popups, and if i close it, there is no options in OS versions dropdown menu except "Download more simulator runtimes...". How can i add this simulator, if it possible in Xcode 12?

[Pairing watches menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3v9C.jpg)

[Components window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2P6b.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling to get a watchOS 4 simulator paired with an iOS sim.

Comment: No, i haven't, this was my pet project, currently on pause. I can only suggest that you try to contact Apple Support directly about this issue.